# problems getting MD5 fingerprint for signing certificate

Tags: md5, keystore, keytool

While using the Google code website, I have tried using the command prompt to follow their instructions:

> First, determine which key you will
>   use to sign your application at
>   release and make sure of the path to
>   the keystore that contains it.
>
> Next, run Keytool with the -list
>   option, against the target keystore
>   and key alias. The table below lists
>   the options you should use.

But I am continuously getting this error:

> C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin>keytool
>   -list keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file
>   does not exist: C:\Documents and
>   Settings\nwashington.keystore

also when I follow the next instruction on the site:

> Here's an example of a Keytool command
>   that generates an MD5 certificate
>   fingerprint for the key alias_name in
>   the keystore my-release-key.keystore

Here is what I wrote and my error:

```
> C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin>keytool
> -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Documents and
> Settings\nwashington.android\debug.keystore
> -storepass android -keypass android keytool error:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage
> error, and is not a legal command
```

Am I not entering the correct "my-release-key"?

Can anyone help me get past this issue/what the error means?

Thank you!

Comment: It might be helpful to add a link to the Google Code page that has the instructions.

Comment: Looks like it's here: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getfingerprint

Comment: For the best reference to the solution of such problem, watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?hl=en-GB&v=vgr4l1nsFdU) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C:\Documents a nd Settings

Is that extra space in "and" the problem, or did that get inserted while you were creating this question?

Maybe you need quotes around the path because it contains spaces?

Comment: thank you for your help. The space in between the and was a typo. No matter what I do/did I would either get an error saying the "file does not exist"(even though that was the correct location of the file) or it said that "and is not a legal command". I have come to the conclusion that it is because I am not an administrator on any of the computers I have been using, where as my group mates have all followed the same steps as me(and were SUCCESSFUL) yet they were all on their own personal computers(not the ones in our computer lab.) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Finally i solve the problem and the correct working script / Command is below: Please note the double quotes where they are placed please use as it is as this is the correct method. and off course please change the user name and as for the different versions of windows you people will have to change it accordingly. Please feel free to ask if you people have any questions.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keys
tore "c:\documents and settings\user\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android
 -keypass android
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a slash between nwashington and .android

```
nwashington\.android
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is probably a little too late to be of help. The problem is probably the lack of quotes around the path - in Windows, a space is used as a separator between arguments, and so, your path will be treated as just "C:\Documents" instead of "C:\Documents and Settings\nwashington.android\debug.keystore"

That is why you get the error stating "and" is not a legal command, since it thinks the previous argument ended when it came across the space.